# Getting a log4j:warn in simple program

Tags: java, jasper-reports, log4j

I'm getting a new error:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

I'm using *NetBeans 7.0.0*. I want to develop reports. I'm already set the  Log4j.jar in my classpath, but still see the error. Can you explain?

Code snippet:

```
try
    {
        System.out.println("Compiling report...");
        JasperReport report =JasperCompileManager.compileReport("D:\\Schoolmngt\\src\\schoolmngt\\FirstReport.jrxml");
        JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("FirstReport.jasper",new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfFile("FirstReport.jasper",new HashMap(),new JREmptyDataSource());
        System.out.println("Done!");
     }
      catch(Exception e)
      {e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a proper log4j configuration. For starters put a

log4j.properties file like the following in the classpath

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```